# 「お疲れ様でした」 word by word meaning vs. actual meaning?

Tags: meaning, morphology

お疲{つか}れ様{さま}でした is made of the following components:

> お + つかれ + さま + でした。

1. A honorific affix (お).
2. Stem of a verb means to get tired (つかれる).
3. A Noun means appearance (さま).
4. And でした.

Literally, it means "You appear tired" which creates meaning **A** in my mind, but actually according to this [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E7%96%B2%E3%82%8C%E6%A7%98%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F#Japanese) it means:

> I appreciate your efforts, thank you very much, good work

which creates meaning **B** in my mind.
Why does an expression that carries the meaning of A word by word, but in actual context gives the meaning of B?

Comment: You're asking what's the logic between "observing (or claiming to observe) that someone is tired" and "appreciating their hard work"?

Comment: @Leebo, My question is that: when I look at this phrase, only the meaning of being tired is created in my mind, and I don't see any part like English "not" in this which changes the meaning literally to "don't be tired".

Comment: It doesn't mean "don't be tired" whatsoever. Maybe you have trouble understanding why "being tired" seems to be a good thing, culturally speaking?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "creates a negative meaning in the mind?" Can you expand on this part? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @jarmanso7, No, I am not discussing from a cultural point of view. Rather, I look at this structure from a morphological point of view. I compare this structure with the structure of the mother tongue and also English language, when I see a tired person, I use the verb to be tired in the negative form to express my encouragement.
But this term does not have any negative form for being tired.

Comment: Though it's an empty phrase now, I think it can be seen as an expression of empathy. The speaker is putting him/herself in the listener's position, like saying I feel your tiredness. There's also ご愁傷様 to express condolences. It seems to be a cultural thing.

Comment: This さま is not the honorific but the word meaning like 'appearance' or 'state', so it's 'You appear tired (because of your hard work)'

Comment: @Angelos:  I don't know if your claim is true or not, but I never thought of it that way, and it blew my mind !

Comment: @Angelos: Yes, according to your valuable note, I checked the entry for さま at [link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A7%98#Japanese). It has several meanings, including the second person pronoun.

Comment: "I use the verb to be tired in the negative form to express my encouragement" But this phrase is **not about** encouragement; it's about *gratitude* for the *result of* the effort that caused the exhaustion.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see it more as the gratitude for the effort itself, regardless of the result, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I think you're right, but I'm glossing over that distinction because I think *that* specific aspect is more cultural. People from other places might struggle more with the idea of appreciating hard work simply because it is hard work, yes.

Comment: @HadiKarimi There is also very similar expression ご苦労様 ("thank you (for your hard work)"), formed from 苦労 (literally "trouble, hardship, difficulty, labor, toil").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new in linguistics topics but I think we can find the right answer in semantics and pragmatics.

Semantics and pragmatics are two different branches of linguistics which the former is involved with the literal meaning of phrases and sentences without considering the context whereas the later deals with meaning in context.

Here I think 「お疲れ様でした」 is a good example that shows difference between semantics and pragmatics in Japanese. It literally means *‘you look tired’*, but in the context which appearing tired is caused by hard work it means *‘appreciating your hard work’*.

Comment: So, your question really was simply about the meaning of the expression, to begin with. I see no reference to any "positive" or "negative" in your own answer...

Comment: @ jarmanso7: Two words positive and negative that I used were not the right choice and caused a lot of confusion. And I modified my question a bit to make it clear.
The origin of this negative and positive came from the fact that our teacher had translated this phrase into Persian as "don't be tired" and as a result, I was looking for a negated letter in Japanese phrase.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying message is "you worked hard, so you are tired". Hard work being commendable.

An aside remark: it rhymes interestingly with a line in a famous Russian rock song "where the (only) measure for work is tiredness". In that context it's a reference to meaningless work, which only noticeable result is tiredness.
So, yes, it's a cultural thing.

Answer (score 3):

> being tired creates a negative meaning in the mind

Sure; generally, we would rather not be tired, than be tired.

Therefore, when someone else has done work, and become tired as a result, we should be grateful.

> why does this term convey a positive meaning like the following:

Because we do not say it to encourage someone to keep going (we have other phrases for that, like 頑張ってください); we say it after the person is done (for now). Pay attention to the translation you found:

> I appreciate your *efforts*, thank you very much, good *work*

Effort and work make people tired. If you point out the fatigue, you also point out its cause.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom, it's a greeting, "Tough job well done." Don't get too deep into analyzing it. It's sort of like taking apart "How do you do?".

But, if you must dive in, otsukaresama is a word on its own, so you really can't separate it and consider it to have the meaning of being tired.

It's often shortened to "otuskare!", just like "How do you do?" may be shortened to "Howdy!"